# MySQL BEFORE INSERT trigger with IF conditions

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6

In my `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, I select data, then I check the value if it's null then I do insert data into table A then else into table B. I select data from a table in another database called `ebsms.inbox` then insert to `dbsmsra_pit2.smsra_sms` and `dbsmsra_pit2.smsra_trash`

Here's my complete code :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXIST dbsmsra_pit2.smsra_sms.filterNoHP;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `filterNoHP`
BEFORE INSERT ON smsra_sms FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE IDx int(11);
DECLARE NumberHP varchar(20);
DECLARE WaktuKirim timestamp;
DECLARE IsiSMS text;

SELECT ID, SenderNumber, ReceivingDateTime,
TextDecoded into IDx, NumberHP, WaktuKirim, IsiSMS FROM ebsms.inbox
WHERE NumberHP in (SELECT NoHP FROM smsra_blokir_number)
and DATE(ReceivingDateTime) = curdate();

IF NumberHP = null then
insert into smsra_sms
set idsms = IDx, SendingDateTime = WaktuKirim,
isi = IsiSMS, pengirim = NumberHP
ON duplicate key update idsms = idsms + IDx;

ELSE
insert into smsra_trash
set Nohp = NumberHP
ON duplicate key update Nohp = Nohp + NumberHP;

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

here's the error message :

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

Please I need help.

Comment: `NumberHP = null` will be never true as nothing is equal to NULL

Comment: Your trigger is `BEFORE INSERT ON smsra_sms`. So it fires when an `INSERT INTO smsra_sms` statement is run. Then why does the trigger *also* insert into `smsra_sms`? Also, it appears your trigger doesn't really depend on what is being inserted by the triggering statement – that doesn't make much sense either. Normally I would expect to find references to `NEW.whatever` in such triggers.

Answer (score 1):

As @dezso says, you can't compare `NULL` with arithmetic comparison operators as described in the [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/working-with-null.html).

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL. To demonstrate this for yourself, try the following
>   query:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Edit this part:

```
IF NumberHP IS null then # <-- IS replaced =
    insert into smsra_sms
    set idsms = IDx, SendingDateTime = WaktuKirim,
    isi = IsiSMS, pengirim = NumberHP
    ON duplicate key update idsms = idsms + IDx;
ELSE
    insert into smsra_trash
    set Nohp = NumberHP
    ON duplicate key update Nohp = Nohp + NumberHP;
END IF;
```

Comment: I got warning, it says : Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: That is because you're trying to add one trigger that already has this action in that table, add before the `DELIMITER $$` of the trigger: `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS database.filterNoHP;`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-trigger.html

Comment: I still got that warning

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you're running? Your complete syntax please.

Comment: I already get what's wrong with my trigger, I had a trigger with same action but with different name. But, my trigger still didn't insert any data into the tables I need

Comment: Can you update your answer with more information abour it?